# Using column index in POI

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am using Apache POI 3.10.1 in a web application. I need to know how I can use column index in lieu of column letter in the setCellFormula:

```
xcell.setCellFormula("SUM(A1:B1)");

//desire to make this all dynamic as I iterate thru columns and rows
xcell.setCellFormula("SUM(01:11)");
```

Comment: Excel requires letters. Why not simply turn the number into a letter?

Answer (score 4):

You can construct a `CellReference`, e.g. via the constructor `CellReference(int pRow, int pCol)` and then retrieve the Excel-style column-strings via `formatAsString()`

And for areas like you use above there is `AreaReference`, which is constructed from two `CellReference` instances and can return the "A1:B1" value.